# Best practice around managing variables

Tags: php

In teaching myself PHP, I have come against a bit of a concern around security. I would very much appreciate some input on the two options below. Likely they are both wrong, although both work... But I would prefer to build on a proper solution.

I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329063/where-to-put-database-connection-settings), and they indicate a few other options, but it is from 7 years ago...
I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957732/can-i-include-code-into-a-php-class), but I am not understanding a single thing in that detailed answer!

The idea is to place all my variables inside a JSON file named global.json in order for Puppet to maintain changes in hostnames, passwords, API tokens etc. So it is fairly sensitive information.

The global.json file is protected via a Directory directive.

It is instantiated via a variables.php file:

```
<?php
  $data = file_get_contents('includes/global.json');
  $config = json_decode($data);

  // Database Variables
  $database_host = $config->{'database'}->{'host'};
  $database_user = $config->{'database'}->{'username'};
  $database_password = $config->{'database'}->{'password'};
  $database_name = $config->{'database'}->{'database'};
  $database_port = $config->{'database'}->{'database'};
?>
```

My main question is around the database functions.

Before I used a JSON file, I would include a dbcontroller file:

```
class DBController {    
    private $host = "192.168.50.3";
    private $user = username;
    private $password = password;
    private $database = database_name;
    private $port = 5432;
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
    }

    function connectDB() {
        $conn = pg_connect("host=$this->host dbname=$this->database user=$this->user password=$this->password");
        return $conn;
    }

function runQuery($query) {
    $result = pg_query($this->conn,$query);
    $resultset = pg_fetch_all($result);

    if(!empty($resultset)) {
        return $resultset;
    }
}
```

}

But, using the JSON file, I 'have' to update that to:

```
class DBController {    
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
    }

    function connectDB() {
        require_once 'includes/variables.php';
        $conn = pg_connect("host=$database_host dbname=$database_name user=$database_user password=$database_password");
        return $conn;
    }

    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = pg_query($this->conn,$query);
        $resultset = pg_fetch_all($result);

        if(!empty($resultset)) {
            return $resultset;
        }
    }
}
```

Is the implementation I use via JSON, (by including the file in the connectDB function) an accepted or at least a proper way to do this?

I suspect a first step will be to place the globals.json file outside the doc root rather than jsut rely on the directive, but any other advise or recommendations?

Comment: Many systems these days will use environment variables to accomplish this job. This is especially handy when you're deploying applications on docker-like infrastructure. For local development, you can use a package like dotenv to get settings from a file.

Comment: wow yeah, I have not considered this approach, but you are correct, this is certainly an option. Initiate them using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php ?

Comment: Yes or via `$_ENV`

Comment: Apologies, you mention this is for local development, how would this change on production systems?Or is the only change there where they will be defined, eg `/etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: This is getting a bit beyond the scope of the original question, but it highly depends on how this is deployed. I would use `dotenv` for local development. On production you might be able to set environment variables in your nginx or apache vhost, or when configuring a docker container.